# Expressing a hypercube subset definition using set notation

Tags: graph-theory, notation

The definition of a hypercube is this:

> The $n $-dimensional hypercube $Q_n$ is the graph with
> $V = \left\{{ (e_1,\dots,e_n)|e_i \in \left\{{0,1}\right\}(i=1,\dots,n)}\right\}$
>
> in which two  vertices are neighbours if and only if the corresponding
> rows differ  in exactly one entry.

How can I write in set notation that I have a specific disjoint subset of the hypercube vertices, which is $\left\{{X,Y}\right\}$ $\left\{{C,V}\right\}$ where $X, Y, C,V$ are vertices  $\left\{{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_i}\right\}$ where $e_i \in \{0,1\}$.

In other words, I want to say that out of all the hypercube $Q_n$ vertices $V$ I have isolated the disjoint subset $\left\{{X,Y}\right\}$ $\left\{{C,V}\right\}$ where each element of that subject is a vertex with $n$ binary digits

Comment: Can you define "disjoint subsets?" Are you trying to isolate non-adjacent vertices? Can you give an example of such subsets on $Q_{3}$?

Comment: @ml0105 yes, an example on $Q_3$ is: $\{000,101\},\{100,001\}$ and another one is $\{110,000\},\{100,010\}$

Comment: So are you trying to isolate $\{000, 101\}$ as those two vertices are non-adjacent? Or are you trying to isolate $\{000, 101\}$ and $\{100, 001\}$ based on the fact that the two sets are disjoint?

Comment: I'm trying to isolate those two (or any two) based on the fact the those two sets are disjoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a set theoretic standpoint, what you would want in terms of vertices is:

$$ \{ \{ a, b \} : a, b \subset V, |a| = |b| = 2, a \cap b = \emptyset\}$$